# How to implement a virtual scrolling FlatList in React Native with Firestore data?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am wondering if anyone has implemented a virtual scrolling FlatList with data provided from firestore? I am currently using onEndReached with a handler that re-fires a firestore query where the 'limit' option is incremented by 10 every time. Works Ok but there is the problem where if I keep scrolling even at the end, the 'limit' value just keeps increasing. What is the best way to achieve what I am after? ( I am not looking for a 'Load more' button. Rather load more data when nearing the end of the list. I am using react-redux-firebase and redux-firestore packages for data retrieval)

Comment: Are you pre-fetching some records ahead of time or your code fetch records on demand?

Comment: Initially fetch 20 records then fetch 10 every time the user reaches the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

On onEndReached **handler**, just check if the length of record in firestore becomes equal or lesser than the total incremented.
Let's say firestore had 103 records and you incremented 10 times now and your list has 100 items on 11th(increment) your list will increment to 110 but there is not that much record in firestore as 103<110 so it shouldn't update the list any.more